# Python progress bar using tqdm

Tags: python-3.7, tqdm

I have written the code below using tqdm module, but I am not getting the output in a single line.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(10)):
   print('Hello')
   time.sleep(3)

10%|█         | 1/10 [00:03<00:27,  3.00s/it]Hello
20%|██        | 2/10 [00:06<00:24,  3.00s/it]Hello
30%|███       | 3/10 [00:09<00:21,  3.00s/it]Hello
40%|████      | 4/10 [00:12<00:18,  3.00s/it]Hello
50%|█████     | 5/10 [00:15<00:15,  3.00s/it]Hello
60%|██████    | 6/10 [00:18<00:12,  3.00s/it]Hello
70%|███████   | 7/10 [00:21<00:09,  3.00s/it]Hello
90%|█████████ | 9/10 [00:27<00:03,  3.00s/it]Hello
100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:30<00:00,  3.00s/it]Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
tqdm.write('Hello')
```

instead of

```
print('Hello')
```

This yields:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:30<00:00,  3.00s/it]
```

Further reading: https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#write

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you use tqdm as you did in your loop and print something afterwards, the bar will be recreated in the next line. You can use something like Mark Allen stated, or avoid printing anything if you only want to track the time left/passed.